# The Wifi Status Speed is a lot more than im able to use

Tags: connection

According to the WiFi status I have 21.5 Mbps. When I try any Internet speed tester it won't go above 0.15. I'm.having to do this on my phone because of how slow the Internet on my computer is. If someone can help me I'll be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

The wifi connection speed is only the speed between you and the wifi access point; So this is the speed you'd be able to transfer data between you and the access point theoretically. (You'll never actually hit this speed in real life tests).

The internet speed also relies on the connection from your ISP, which is terminated (normally) at the access point - this is the speed you're seeing when you do a speed test.

If you imagine that your wifi link to the access point is a motorway, behind that motorway is your ISP's connection, which is a small 20 km/h side road which your data must also travel down, when you're doing a speed test online.